# Removing the (0) on the WooCommerce Reviews Tab

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, review

I've succeeding in removing the (0) on the Reviews tab heading when there is no reviews. In marketing - it's probably best practice to not show that a product has 0 reviews. Here is the code that I have placed in my child theme's functions.php file which is found in the WooCommerce plugin file wc-template-function.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_default_product_tabs' ) ) {

/**
 * Add default product tabs to product pages.
 *
 * @param array $tabs
 * @return array
 */
function woocommerce_default_product_tabs( $tabs = array() ) {
    global $product, $post;

    // Description tab - shows product content
    if ( $post->post_content ) {
        $tabs['description'] = array(
            'title'    => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 10,
            'callback' => 'woocommerce_product_description_tab'
        );
    }

    // Additional information tab - shows attributes
    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || ( $product->enable_dimensions_display() && ( $product->has_dimensions() || $product->has_weight() ) ) ) ) {
        $tabs['additional_information'] = array(
            'title'    => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 20,
            'callback' => 'woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab'
        );
}

    // Reviews tab - shows comments
    if ( comments_open() ) {
    $check_product_review_count = $product->get_review_count();
    if ( $check_product_review_count == 0 ) {
        $tabs['reviews'] = array(
            'title'    => sprintf( __( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' ) ),
            'priority' => 30,
            'callback' => 'comments_template'
        );
        }
        else {
        $tabs['reviews'] = array(
            'title'    => sprintf( __( 'Reviews (%d)', 'woocommerce', $product->get_review_count() ), $product->get_review_count() ),
            'priority' => 30,
            'callback' => 'comments_template'
        );
        }
    }

    return $tabs;
}
}
```

My question is - is this the most efficient way of modifying this without changing the core files of woocommerce? The function "woocommerce_default_product_tabs" is a pluggable function, but it seems like I could somehow use a filter instead of copying this entire function into my child theme and editing it from there. I just need to get at this line of code:

```
title'    => sprintf( __( 'Reviews (%d)', 'woocommerce', $product->get_review_count() ),
```

And add an if statement to check if there is no comments to change this above line like in the line above:

```
title'    => sprintf( __( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' ),
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's pretty easy. You can change the title of any tabs:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wp_woo_rename_reviews_tab', 98);
function wp_woo_rename_reviews_tab($tabs) {
    global $product;
    $check_product_review_count = $product->get_review_count();
    if ( $check_product_review_count == 0 ) {
        $tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'Reviews';
    } else {
        $tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'Reviews('.$check_product_review_count.')';
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

---

Comment: Yeah - that did it. Thanks for your help Alex.

Comment: thanks for shearing. i want if review 0 then hide total . i mean REVIEWS
There are no reviews yet. will hide. any idea how

Comment: @pagol How is anyone going to post a review if they can't get to the review tab because it is hidden?